# Change serverless.yml stage depending on git branch

Tags: node.js, bitbucket, cicd

I have a nodejs project set up with bitbucket ci/cd - is there any way to programmatically change the Stage from dev to what ever git branch I am on?

Serverless.yml:

stage: ${opt:stage, "dev"}

I have tried to use this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-git-variables)
but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Hi, a `git repo` is defined by the hidden `.git` directory present inside the repo itself, if you are on linux based system you can find the folder using the following command in your terminal inside your project

```
ls -al
```

Inside the .git you can find a file called `HEAD` that contains the current head branch for the project
ie:
`ref: refs/heads/3-implement-some feature`

## Conlcusion

Basically what i mean is that you can access to this file inside your project and define your desired custom logic.
I hope this can help you in some way.